# Como uma aplicação Ionic se conecta a um servidor?

Tags: api, ionic, mobile, servidor, http-request

**Criando uma Calculadora Cliente/Servidor Mobile**

---

- Crie uma calculadora em que o usuário digite dois números e submeta
  para um servidor calcular
- O servidor irá fazer o cálculo e sua aplicação irá mostra o resultado
  para o usuário
- O servidor já está implementado aqui:
  https://www.fernandoxavier.com.br/ensino/calculadora/calculo.php
- Esse servidor espera dois valores via GET (x e y) e retorna a soma
  deles.
- Um exemplo de requisição seria:
  https://www.fernandoxavier.com.br/ensino/calculadora/calculo.php?x=10&y=9
- Logo, a sua tarefa será criar apenas o lado do cliente usando Ionic

---

Já criei o app em ionic, mas como jogo a url desse servidor no meu código?
Pelo que eu entendi, tenho que importar uma API de HTTP, e instalar um provider... Mas como faz isso?

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, é bem simples. Basta importar a bilioteca Native Http do ionic e fazer as requisições ao sevidor necessário.
[Documentação Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/)

Exemplo:

```
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http';

constructor(private http: HTTP) {}
this.http.get('http://enderecoservidor.io', {}, {})
  .then(data => {

    console.log(data.status);
    console.log(data.data); // data received by server
    console.log(data.headers);

  })
```